# String Insert at a certain line

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2012, insert

I am using Visual Basic.net.

If I have a string that has many lines in it, is it possible to insert a string at a certain line? I see that there is an insert function for strings. Is there a function to insert a string at a certain line of another string?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a function to insert a string at a certain line of another
>   string?

No, because a string is not a list/array of lines. You have to split it by `Environment.NewLine` to get an array, `ToList` to get a `List(Of String)` which has an [`Insert` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.insert.aspx). Then you can use `String.Join` to put it together after you have inserted it:

```
Dim lines = MultiLineText.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
lines.Insert(2, "test") ' will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if there are less than 2 lines '
Dim result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings have no idea what a "line" is. A string is only a sequence of characters. What you can do is to convert your string into a list of individual lines (for example as `List<string>`) and then insert into that list.

```
List<string> listOfLines = new List<string>();
listOfLines.AddRange(sourceString.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None));

listOfLines.Insert(13, "I'm new here");

string result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, listOfLines);
```

This is C# code, but I'm pretty sure you can easily convert this to VB.NET.

Comment: Please see Tim Schmelter's answer for a Visual Basic version of my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no string methods that handles a string as a collections of lines. You can use the `Insert` method, but you have to find out where in the string to put the line yourself.

Example:

```
' Where to insert
Dim line As Integer = 4
' What to insert
Dim content As String = "asdf"

' Locate the start of the line
Dim pos As Integer = 0
Dim breakLen As Integer = Environment.Newline.Length
For i As Integer = 0 to line
  pos = text.IndexOf(Environment.Newline, pos + breakLen)
Next

' Insert the line
text = text.Insert(pos, content + Environment.Newline)
```